# Create an Empty dataframe with schema: TypeError: array() argument 1 must be a unicode character, not StringType

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, schema

i want create an empty dataframe to start from this schema.

```
schema=StructType([StructField('COMPARTIMENTO',StringType()),StructField('CONFERMATO',StringType()),StructField('CORSIA',ArrayType(StringType()))])

df_empty=self.spark.createDataFrame(self.sc.emptyRDD(),schema=schema)
```

but when i run my python script with spark2-submit
i have this error:
**TypeError: array() argument 1 must be a unicode character, not StringType**

Some tips for me?
thanks
Regards

Comment: Do you have a space between your code and "\" -- specifically on the first line?

Comment: schema=StructField('COMPARTIMENTO',StringType()),StructField('CONFERMATO',StringType()),StructField("CORSIA",ArrayType(StringType()))
also this i have  same error!!!!

Comment: I ran the above code in the Pyspark shell (Python 2 and 3) and it ran without any issues (Spark 2.3.1)